# error : 302 Moved Temporarily gerrit

Tags: git, debian, gerrit

I am trying to install `Gerrit` on Debian 9, but I have a problem.

When I take to download Initialize the Site, console informs me `error 302 Moved Temporarily` while downloading `bcprov-jdk16-144.jar`. The error snapshot is attached.

[image]

I use this guideline https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/install-quick.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gerrit 2.2.2 is a too old version (2012) try to re-execute the "java init" command but using the [gerrit-2.14.3.war](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/download/gerrit-2.14.3.war) file instead. I suggest do not use the "--batch" option so you can see all options required (there're defaults for every one) and change any option that is causing error.